# tracking outgoing anchor click to separate account

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a site that has implemented Google Analytics. However I need to track an outgoing anchor link to another domain url and that tracking to be submitted to another Google Analytics account.

Comment: You can use standard outbound link tracking methods, but to send the hit to a secondary account you may need to do that through a secondary tracker that you have already created on your site. You can find out more about multiple trackers here https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032400?hl=en

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this? I can't think of a good reason and there may be a better way to get the information you're looking for.

Comment: @kevintechie because there's already implemented account in the website so I need to avoid submitting any tracking data to it. Instead I'm sending data to another account that is on the domain that the outbound link is referring to.

Comment: You'll get referral data automatically so there's no need to send extra data to the target of the outbound link. If you're tracking specific campaigns then you'll want to use custom campaign tracking URLs. You can use this tool to create URLs: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en.

Answer (score 1):

1) Outbound Link Tracking - This is best done through event tracking on the outbound link. The following code is from google:

```
<script>
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {'hitCallback':
     function () {
     document.location = url;
     }
   });
}
</script>
```

Then add the onclick attribute to your outbound link that you want to track

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.com'); return false;">Check out example.com</a>
```

2) Inbound Link Tracking - This is best done through UTM tags. You should make the `utm_source=MyWebsite`. Then you can see all the traffic that came from your first website as referral -> Source

More info:
Outbound link tracking - https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en
UTM Tracking / Tagging - https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en

Comment: The outbound link tracking code above will not send data to the second account. It will only send data to the primary account.

Comment: @kevintechie - Thats correct, event tracking will only work for the current site that the person is on, which is why I also talk about UTM tagging of the external link. UTM tags will let you know where your traffic came from.

Comment: Yes, but it's duplicate information unless it's a source that doesn't have referral data (like e-mail) or you want to track a specific campaign. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1247839?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

What I've researched is:

Register the second tracker that the tracking info should be sent to, giving it a name:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-Y', 'none', {'name': 'nameThatTracker'});
```

Then on click of the outbound link / anchor :

```
ga('nameThatTracker.send', 'event', 'click', 'page-visit', '');
```

As [@Bradley4 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26566611/485911) shows one can add any parameters to the call that suits him/her.